# Need information about Oracle database provider for Entity Framework Core

Tags: oracle11g

I want to use Entity Framework Core with Oracle 11 database. So, i need information about Oracle data provider for Entity Framework core. Free of cost.

Answer (score 1):

#### Entity Framework Core have options for Oracle 11g, 12 and latest!!

Add latest **NuGet**s to your project:

- **Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore** (2.19.30)
- **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core** (2.19.31)

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

...

    public class BaseDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected static String _connectionString = "";
        public static void SetConnection(string connectionString) { _connectionString = connectionString; }
        public BaseDbContext() : base() { }
    }

    public class OracleDbContext : BaseDbContext
    {
        public OracleDbContext() : base() { }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseOracle(_connectionString);  //latest
            //optionsBuilder.UseOracle(_connectionString, options => options.UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11"));  // 11g
            //optionsBuilder.UseOracle(_connectionString, options => options.UseOracleSQLCompatibility("12"));
        }
    }

    public class AppDbContext : OracleDbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext() : base() { }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbQuery<TopCustomer> TopCustomers { get; set; }
    }

...
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
...                
        BaseDbContext.SetConnection(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["DefaultConnection"]);

...
```

**appsettings.json**:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "User Id=<YourUserId>;Password=<yourPassword>;Data Source=<Your Db IP or dns>:<db-port>/<servicename>;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

On windows, where you have OCI driver with **tnsnames.ora** and **sqlnet.ora** installed, just add **EZCONNECT** param to your **sqlnet.ora** file, as below:

**NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, HOSTNAME, EZCONNECT)**

Works fine on windows without any Oracle driver, only need of the oracle DLLs in  your project!